# sqlalchemy core process remains 'idle in transaction'

Tags: sqlalchemy, transactions

I'm using sqlAlchemy core to access a postgres db. I'm having a problem dropping a table after I do a select from it. Looking at the CPU processes (ps -aux |grep postgres) I can see that the drop command is waiting. It appears that it is waiting for the select statement to clear, which should have occurred. I did the select and processed all the rows so that should end the select process. I've even tried to close the cursor but that didn't do anything. About the only thing I can do is to close the connection, but I don'think I should have to recreate a connection for every db query or should I?

Below is a basic idea of how the drop is hanging.

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://***:***@localhost:5432/Junk')
metadata = MetaData()
temp_table = Table('index_tmp', metadata,
                       Column('pid', Integer, primary_key = True),
                       Column('match_id', Integer),
                       Column('id', Integer)
                       )
people = Table('people', metadata, schema='public', autoload=True,          autoload_with=engine)

metadata.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()

sel = select([func.min(people.c.id).label('match_id'), people.c.id])
ins = temp_table.insert().from_select(['match_id', 'id'], sel)
conn.execute(ins)

result = conn.execute(select([tmp_table]))
#Here the process shows "idle in transaction"

result.fetchall()
#This closes the cursor but the process is still "idle in transaction"

temp_table.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
#The script will hang here since the select command is still "idle in  transaction" and blocking this drop.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to see what the problem is from your example, but I expect that a variable was assigned an `sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy` object which is not garbate collected. For example this creates two hung transactions:

```
one = engine.execute("select 1");
two = engine.execute("select 2");
```

...

```
test=# select state,query from pg_stat_activity where application_name != 'psql';
        state        |  query
---------------------+----------
 idle in transaction | select 1
 idle in transaction | select 2
(2 rows)
```

In your example `del(result)`, `result.fetchall()`, and `result.close()` would all issue a `ROLLBACK`.

You can also avoid this behavior altogether by instructing SQLAlchemy/psycopg2 not to create implicit transactions:

```
engine = create_engine(uri, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
```